# C# Add variable to List by iterating name

Tags: c#, list, loops

Is there a way I can add Values to a List by iterating? I have a form with all the variables declared and a class to collect all the information. But I'm trying to learn a way to add all this through code instead of having so much repeated code.

```
namespace WinForm
```

{

```
public partial class Form_Destrezas : Form
{
    //Fields
    Tab_Destreza Personales;
    Tab_Destreza Salud;
    Tab_Destreza Participacion;
    Tab_Destreza Convivencia;
    Tab_Destreza Limpieza;
    Tab_Destreza Alimentos;
    Tab_Destreza Ropa;
    Tab_Destreza Libre;
    Tab_Destreza Futuro;


    public Form_Destrezas()
    {
        Personales.AddRow(Personales_1RowNoApp,
                          Personales_1RowNoDom,
                          Personales_1RowEnPro,
                          Personales_1RowDomina,
                          Personales_1RowCheckBox)

    //What I want to do
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Personales.AddRow(Personales_[i]RowNoApp,
                          Personales_[i]RowNoDom,
                          Personales_[i]RowEnPro,
                          Personales_[i]RowDomina,
                          Personales_[i]RowCheckBox)
        }


        this.Text = $"Destrezas - {StudentData.Name}";
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Personales_1RowNoDom_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Personales.checkRow();
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Data for each row will be collected here.
/// </summary>
public class RowData
{
    //Fields
    public List<RadioButton> RadioButtons;
    public CheckBox TeacherVerified;
    public string ActiveStatus = "No Applica";
    public bool verified = false;

    //Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Input row information collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="noApp">Radiobutton "No Applica" for Row.</param>
    /// <param name="noDom">Radiobutton "No Domina" for Row.</param>
    /// <param name="enProc">Radiobutton "En Processo" for Row.</param>
    /// <param name="domina">Radiobutton "Domina" for Row.</param>
    /// <param name="EviMaestro">CheckBox if was verified.</param>
    public void AddRow(RadioButton noApp, RadioButton noDom, RadioButton enProc,
        RadioButton domina, CheckBox EviMaestro)
    {
        var personalesRows = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
        RadioButtons.Add(noApp);
        RadioButtons.Add(noDom);
        RadioButtons.Add(enProc);
        RadioButtons.Add(domina);
        TeacherVerified = EviMaestro;
        checkRow();

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Collects Data from row.
    /// </summary>
    public void checkRow()
    {

        foreach (var Button in RadioButtons)
        {

            if (Button.Checked)
            {
                ActiveStatus = Button.Text;
            }
        }
        if (TeacherVerified.Checked == true)
        {
            verified = TeacherVerified.Checked;
        }
    }


}

public class Tab_Destreza : RowData
{



}
```

}

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i == 10; i++)` Do you mean `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`?

Comment: Yes! But in the end I have all these variables declared on a WinForm. What I'm trying to do is add them to a class for easy access.

Comment: You need to use reflection

Comment: You need to stop having unique names and have an array or some other collection for your items.  That way you can use `Personales[i]`.  You are also likely to be better off with a class or struct rather than individual variables

Comment: You really need an [mcve]. You need to particularly show the `Tab_Destreza` definition. We need to be able to copy-paste-and-run your code.

Comment: @Deovi Hey I provided you a good solution but it's not completed because I need you to provide some few additional details. Please check my answer at the bottom of it, and comment out an answer to these concerns. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would build a sequence on which each element would be a map of each row's class field name and their corresponding values:

```
var personalesRowMaps = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("Personales_"))
        // f.Name.Split(...) part explained: each field has an underscore,
        // where the next character after it is the row index. Thus, 
        // I split the name using the underscore and I get the right part 
        // of the field identifier, and then I get the first character of
        // that part: the row index.
        .Select(f => new { Index = f.Name.Split('_')[1][0], Field = f })
        .GroupBy(o => o.Index)
        .Select(g => g.ToList().ToDictionary(o => o.Field.Name, o => o.Field.GetValue(this)));
```

Step by step:

1. We get all fields from the current `class`.
2. We filter out all fields so we could work on ones with the `"Personales_"` prefix.
3. We project each found field into an object of two properties: **(1)** we extract the number (the index) of the row to which the field belongs to (i.e. Personales_**1**XXX), **(2)** the reflected class field.
4. We group all fields by the extracted row index
5. We project each resulting row index grouped fields into a dictionary, where keys are the *field names* and the values the *field values*.

Once you've built that map, adding the whole rows is an easy task. You just need to iterate each dictionary and add each field to `Personales`, where the *row index* will be the index of the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < personalRowMaps.Count; i++)
{
     var rowMap = personalRowMaps[i];

     Personales.AddRow
     (
         rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowNoApp"],
         rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowNoDom"],
         rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowEnPro"],
         rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowDomina"],
         rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowCheckBox"]
     );
}
```

<strike>**Notes:**</strike>

- You need to clarify if the class fields are `private`, `protected` or `public`. For now, I'll think that they're `private` (see the binding flags on the LINQ query). Please comment out what access modifier have these class fields.
- Also, I need to know what's the type of those class fields? DataRow, DataColumn, DataCell... or what? I need this to complete the answer, as for now each field value is typed as `object`...
  **THE OP HAS ALREADY PROVIDED THE REQUIRED INFO!**

Comment: This doesn't replicate what the OP is doing. But, the OP didn't provide a full set of code with class definitions so it's difficult to know what to do.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hey. BTW, isn't the OP trying to add all rows held by class fields having an identifier starting with `Personales_` prefix? I understood that this was the goal. What did you understand instead? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `.AddRow(...)` method takes 5 parameters. The one in your code only takes 1.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oops! I didn't notice that... I'll fix this, thank you

Comment: It's certainly better, but now you need to know the types of each parameter.

Comment: @Enigmativity Argh, you're right. This happens when you try to address a question which lacks a lot of details... I'll add a note... I guess that those fields' type should be something like a data column or cell, or who knows...

Comment: I updated the Form information and you can see the other tabs on it such as Salud.

Comment: Hey Matías! Yes the fields in this class are composed of 4 radioButtons and one checkbox. I have 9 tabs with 10 rows each. The fields where set as Private. I tested your code and it dies detect all fields but for some reason the I tested your code and for some reason .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("Personales_")) seems to be returning a null but I checked it while debugging an it shows it there and it seems to be part of a dictionary.

Comment: Ok I found the data on the object you created Matías. Now Im working on testing the for loop.

Comment: I'm getting **Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'** for the loop and **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'** 

I got this after creating `public object personalRowMaps= new object();`

Comment: @Deovi Oh! I see you get to fix your own code with my suggested approach. I'm glad you got it :)

Comment: @Deovi One question: do `AddRow` method parameters are of type `object`?

Comment: @Deovi Oops, nevermind, I see what types they're in your source code. So I understand that you could managed to use my suggested code casting each field value to its type? For example: `(RadioButton)rowMap[$"Personales_{i}RowNoApp"]`?

Comment: Why I got a downvote? I would love to know what's wrong.